# Mat2[][] = Mat --> is changing one of them meant to change the other?

Tags: java

What I'm asking (with this code below for example) is whether objects really do have this direct effect on each other once you claim that they're equal or am I just missing something here?

The fix I could find for that issue for now is equaling every single part from one matrix to the other in a for loop, is there perhaps a more efficient/comfortable way to do that(in the case where I'm right about objects effecting one another in the way mentioned)?

public class Matrices {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean mat[][] = {
            {true,true,true},
            {true,true,true},
            {true,true,true}
    };
    boolean mat2[][] = mat;
    aaa(mat,mat2);

}
public static void aaa(boolean mat[][], boolean mat2[][]){
    mat[0][0] = false;
    System.out.println(mat2[0][0]); //gives false
    mat2[0][1] = false;
    System.out.println(mat[0][1]); //gives false
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
boolean mat2[][] = mat;
```

doesn't create a copy of the 2D array, it just creates another reference that refers to the same array.  You are accessing the same array through both references, so the `false` you set through the first array is the same `false` you obtain from the second array.

Comment: Aah, right, because I just gave it the same address! silly me :P But then, what replacement would you suggest for that case? Is creating a for loop the best way to make that copy work?

Comment: You can create your copy array, then you can use two nested `for` loops to copy the data from one array to the other.  Then the two can vary independently.